# In Realm in Android is it possible to do Inter Process Communication?

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to do inter-process communication in Realm (Java, Android). So, say, if we update value of a field of RealmObject from one Process, will we get trigger on RealmChangeListener (corresponding to the mentioned RealmObject) in another process. I assume Realm's version is at least 2.0.2.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm 2.0.0 and beyond supports interprocess notifications for non-encrypted Realms, but there [are some edge cases that aren't covered yet (multi-process migrations, primarily).](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1300#issuecomment-247699111)

---

---

I've put together a sample project and it works for me.

In here, the RecyclerView shows the dog inserted from a broadcast receiver that belongs to a remote process.

```
10-11 20:53:46.340 7302-7302/com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example I/MainActivity: Activity in Process [7302]
10-11 20:53:46.344 7302-7302/com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example D/RealmManager: Incrementing Activity Count [0]: opening Realm.
10-11 20:53:46.352 7302-7302/com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example D/RealmManager: Increment: Count [1]

10-11 20:54:01.352 7560-7560/com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example:remote D/AlarmReceiver: Alarm received in process [7560]
10-11 20:54:01.352 7560-8705/com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example:remote I/AlarmReceiver: Inserting DOGE [Juice]
```

---

Complete source code:

```
public class RealmManager {
    private static final String TAG = "RealmManager";

    static Realm realm;

    static RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    public static RealmConfiguration buildDefaultRealmConfiguration() {
        return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
    }

    public static void initializeRealmConfig(Context appContext) {
        if(realmConfiguration == null) {
            Realm.init(appContext);
            Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Realm configuration.");
            setRealmConfiguration(buildDefaultRealmConfiguration());
        }
    }

    public static void setRealmConfiguration(RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration) {
        RealmManager.realmConfiguration = realmConfiguration;
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }

    private static int activityCount = 0;

    public static Realm getRealm() {
        return realm;
    }

    public static void incrementCount() {
        if(activityCount == 0) {
            if(realm != null) {
                if(!realm.isClosed()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected open Realm found.");
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing Activity Count [0]: opening Realm.");
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        }
        activityCount++;
        Log.d(TAG, "Increment: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
    }

    public static void decrementCount() {
        activityCount--;
        Log.d(TAG, "Decrement: Count [" + activityCount + "]");
        if(activityCount <= 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Decrementing Activity Count: closing Realm.");
            activityCount = 0;
            realm.close();
            if(Realm.compactRealm(realmConfiguration)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Realm compacted successfully.");
            }
            realm = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RealmManager.initializeRealmConfig(getApplicationContext());
        Log.i(TAG, "Activity in Process [" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "]");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        RealmManager.incrementCount(); //lazy for retained fragment
        realm = RealmManager.getRealm();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Dog, DogViewHolder>(this, realm.where(Dog.class).findAllAsync(), true) {
            @Override
            public DogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                return new DogViewHolder(textView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(DogViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.bind(getData().get(position));
            }
        });

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        addNotification(alarmManager, pendingIntent, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    public void addNotification(AlarmManager alarmManager, PendingIntent pendingIntent, long timeOfNotification) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification, pendingIntent);
        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification, pendingIntent);
        } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOfNotification, pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        RealmManager.decrementCount();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;

    public DogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView;
    }

    public void bind(Dog dog) {
        textView.setText(dog.getName());
    }
}
```

---

```
public enum DogNames {
    Jack,
    Jill,
    Joe,
    Jarble,
    Juice,
    Jen,
    Jim,
    Munch,
    Slurp,
    Boop,
    Largo,
    Boson,
    Pete,
    Boner,
    Derp,
    Roger,
    Bunbun,
    Twix,
    Dog
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    Executor executor;

    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm received in process [" + android.os.Process.myPid() + "]");
        Realm.init(context);
        if(realmConfiguration == null) {
            realmConfiguration = RealmManager.buildDefaultRealmConfiguration();
        }
        if(executor == null) {
            executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        }
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try(Realm r = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration)) {
                if(Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "UI thread transaction: this should be fixed!");
                }
                r.executeTransaction(realm -> {
                    Dog dog = new Dog();
                    long id = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll().size()+1;
                    dog.setId(id);
                    dog.setName(DogNames.values()[((Long)id).intValue() % DogNames.values().length].name());
                    realm.insert(dog);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Inserting DOGE [" + dog.getName() + "]");
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://clojars.org/repo/"}
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zhuinden.realm_multiprocess_example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1"

    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'

    apt 'dk.ilios:realmfieldnameshelper:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: I have seen this page. But I am not observing the expected behavior. Do you have some working example?

Comment: Well, what is the expected behavior, and how does it not happen? The `waitForChange` in SharedRealm should handle this.

Comment: In place of trigger, waitForChange will be blocking in nature.

Comment: Not what I meant. Realm already runs a daemon thread which listens to updates via `waitForChange`.  It should be notified of commits in other processes as well.

Comment: Then this daemon should call all listeners belonging to the process. But for me it's not happening. Do I need to configure something, or I am missing something. Please provide some pointers. I will debug additionally.

Comment: Realm trigger is not happening on UI thread. So for background threads with loopers  changeListeners is getting triggered, but same is not happening for UI thread.

Comment: @nature1729 Realm treat UI thread just like any other looper thread. Did you close the Realm instance in the UI thread? If that is the case, no notification will be sent to UI thread from other thread/process.

Comment: @beeender I didn't close it. Let me debug more on it, I will inform you all soon

Comment: You should make sure your RealmResults is preserved as a *field* variable,