# Realm - Realm.init(this) failed in onCreate?

Tags: android, realm

I put Realm.init(this) in the onCreate of my Application class.

But it throws an exception while I'm calling Realm.getDefaultInstance() in the onCreate of my Activity.

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2511)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before calling this method.
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:208)
    at com.kimi.fastdb.PrefActivity.getRealmHelper(PrefActivity.java:1724)
    at com.kimi.fastdb.PrefActivity.onCreate(PrefActivity.java:270)
    at com.kimi.fastdb.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:464)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6308)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
```

Why the realm instance not been initialized after my Application starts?
And how to fix it?

Application:

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .schemaVersion( REALM_DATABASE_VERSION ) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                    .migration( migration ) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
        //          .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build();
        Realm.compactRealm( realmConfiguration );
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

    }
    ...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:allowClearUserData="true"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
...

</application>
```

Comment: Your application is registered in manifest?

Comment: Seems you did not add the Application class to the manifest

Comment: It's registered in manifest. This application is already on Google Play. Only one device report this issue to me(Android 6.0 ZenFone 2 (ZE551ML) (Z00A_1).

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: It looks mostly like a bug on the Zenfone in that case. Which is really unfortunate to say the least. Has the error been reported more than once?

Comment: I'd consider calling `Realm.init(this)` from a BaseActivity of sorts.

Comment: Yes, I got another report yesterday night. It's from Xperia X (F5121). Both of them are Android 6.0. If I put it in the onCreate of the BaseActivity, wouldn't it be called twice after user rotates the screen or the application is restoring from killed(which the application is still in the memory)?

Comment: Probably, but the second call is a no-op.

Comment: @KimiChiu `realm.init()` stores the `applicationContext` for the first time, and if it's not null, then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.

Comment: This is why lately I've been moving [the initialization logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981063/in-realm-in-android-is-it-possible-to-do-inter-process-communication/39981916#39981916) to a BaseActivity and enforce it to execute only once, rather than from Application - sometimes weird issues happen with Application. :( Samsung devices can return `null` as `getFilesDir()` on first start-up, for example.

Answer (score 19):

Try :

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

If you have specific configuration :

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration yourConfg);
```

After that, you can begin transaction and commit it.

Comment: yes men first `realm.init` next `realm.setConfiguration` only work version of 2.0 to up

Answer (score 0):

Add REALM configuration:

```
    Realm.init(this)
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```